# A hollow black hole & quantum entanglement?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, quantum-entanglement

Let us consider the following thought experiment.

we create an entangled pair of particles and we separate them. next, we would place 1 particle inside a massive hollow sphere and the other particle outside. Then we plug the hole to which the entangled particle came in so we have a uniform sphere. Next, we compress the sphere to such a high density that a black hole (spherical in form) forms. We then observe the entangled particle which is outside of the black sphere (or the other one for that matter, just one of the two, although we would not be able to observe it unless we would be inside of the sphere I suppose).

What would we see? would the entanglement be broken the moment the black sphere forms (which would be odd since there was no physical interaction directly to the 2 particles)? Or would we collapse the entanglement at the moment of measurement (which I do not see as a violation of the laws of physics since no information is transported between the 2 particles)? or would the two particles be in a constant state of entanglement (which I find unlikely myself)?

Comment: Entanglement, even if a peculiarity of quantum physics, is a statistical correlation. No influence between one particle and the other. Your thought experiment assumes a particular interpretation of entanglement, which has no experimental evidence, other than quantum statistics.